# Nodejs S3 Delete Multiple Objects Error

Tags: arrays, node.js, express, amazon-s3

I am trying to bulk delete my s3 objects that are associated with one specific blog record in my database, but I'm getting hung up on how to pass the array to my params object to be used in the `s3.deleteObjects` method, but I'm held up on this error: `Check with error message InvalidParameterType: Expected params.Delete.Objects[0].Key to be a string`. I feel like it could be related to not having a loop at some point in the process or maybe the format of the values being passed to my `s3File` array.

**Here is the my routing:**

```
.delete(function(req, res){

models.File.findAll({
    where: {
      blogId: blog.blogId
    }
}).then(function(file){

var s3Files = [];

            function s3Key(link){
                var parsedUrl = url.parse(link);
                var fileName = parsedUrl.path.substring(1);
                return fileName;
            }


            for(var k in file){
                console.log('Here are each files ' + file[k].fileName);
                s3Files.push(s3Key(file[k].fileName));
            }

            console.log('Here are the s3Files ' + s3Files);

            //GOTTEN TO THIS POINT WITHOUT AN ERROR
            aws.config.update({accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY, secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY, region: process.env.AWS_REGION});



            //var awsKeyPath = s3Key(file.fileName);

            var s3 = new aws.S3();

            var options = {
              Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
              Delete: {
                Objects: [{
                    Key: s3Files
                }],
                },
            };

            s3.deleteObjects(options, function(err, data){
                if(data){
                    console.log("File successfully deleted");
                } else {
                    console.log("Check with error message " + err);
                }
            });
});
```

**Here is the output from `console.log('Here are each files ' + file[k].fileName);`:**

```
Here are each files https://local-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/1/2017-02-12/screen_shot_2017-02-01_at_8_25_03_pm.png
Here are each files https://local-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/1/2017-02-13/test.xlsx
Here are each files https://local-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/1/2017-02-13/screen-shot-2017-02-08-at-8.23.37-pm.png
```

**Here is the output from `console.log('Here are the s3Files ' + s3Files);`:**

```
Here are the s3Files 1/2017-02-12/screen_shot_2017-02-01_at_8_25_03_pm.png,1/2017-02-13/test.xlsx,1/2017-02-13/screen-shot-2017-02-08-at-8.23.37-pm.png
```

**Here is the error message:**

```
Check with error message InvalidParameterType: Expected params.Delete.Objects[0].Key to be a string
```

Comment: here is the doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#deleteObjects-property

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Key should be a string. You should use array of Object to Objects.
Use this code :

```
var objects = [];
for(var k in file){
  objects.push({Key : file[k].fileName});
}
var options = {
  Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
  Delete: {
    Objects: objects
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

**Change your array as an object**

```
const objects = [
  {Key: 'image1.jpg'},
  {Key: 'image2.jpg'}
]
```

**Add a new item to the list**

```
for(var k in file){
  objects.push({Key : file[k].fileName});
}
```

**Set the array as Objects value in parameters**

```
const options = {
    Bucket: process.env.BUCKET,
    Delete: {
        Objects: objects,
        Quiet: false
    }
};
```

**Now delete objects**

```
 s3.deleteObjects(options, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

[Learn more from official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#deleteObjects-property)